# How to get top 3 values from array in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a sorted array in descending order such as with values `100 , 98, 96, 90 ...`.
and I am using `foreach()` loop to iterate over the array and use `if condition` with limit `3` such as `

```
foreach($array as $arr){
if(loop_counter<3)
{ 
 echo 'something'; 
}}
```

to get top `3` positions. but the problem is that if there exist two same values such as `100 , 98, 98, 96, 90 . .` then limits should increase from `3` to `4` so that on position `2` there exist two values `98, 98` and position `3` contain value `90` instead of `2nd` `98`.
thanks in advance

Comment: [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: do you need both (duplicated) members?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, does that dupe take into account the possibilities of duplicate values in the data?

Comment: @NigelRen check the second link on closed question.

Comment: Yes I need both duplicate number on one position such as if in exam 2 student have same marks they stand against one position.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam this is different from the rest and already asked questions...

Comment: @AbdullaNilam so remove it from the closed..

Comment: @Mani Ask the question again then add `I need both duplicate number on one position`, i have an answer